mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x1000 and 512x128)
I am doing an anthracnose disease detection on carabao mango using Google Colab. I am currently using the ResNet18 model with Training, Validation, and Testing datasets.
class MangoDiseaseDetection(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
      super(MangoDiseaseDetection, self).__init__()
      self.base_model = models.resnet18(pretrained = True)
      self.base_model.requires_grade = False #This will freeze the pre-trained layer
      
      self.detection = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(512, 128),
          nn.ReLU(inplace = True),
          nn.Dropout(p = 0.5),
          nn.Linear(128, 1),
          nn.Sigmoid()
      )

  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.base_model(x)
      x = self.detection(x)
      return x

# Instatiation of the model
model = MangoDiseaseDetection()

criterion = nn.BCELoss() #Binary Cross Entropy Loss
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)

def train(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader):
  model.train() # model training mode
  epoch_loss = 0.0

  for images, labels in tqdm(train_loader, unit = "batch"):
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # Forward pass and loss calculation
      outputs = model(images)
      loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())

      # Backword pass and update of parameter
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      epoch_losee += loss.item() # Accumulation loss for epoch

  return epoch_loss / len(train_loader) # Average loss per batch.

# Validation Function

def validate (model, criterion, val_loader):
    model.eval() # model to evaluation mode
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in val_loader:
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())

# Train and validate the model

train_losses = []
val_losses = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} / {epochs}")
    train_loss = train(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader)
    val_loss = validate(model, criterion, val_loader)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    print(f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Validation Loss {val_loss:.4f}")

Then I am having this error:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x1000 and 512x128)

How to resolve it?
